# Perl sub made from string

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am trying to use a sub in perl that is contained in a string.

Currently I have something like

```
$sub = "sub{ my $in = shift; if($in =~ /bla.*wam/){return 1;}}";
```

I try and use it by doing

```
$sub->("test");
```

or

```
&{$sub}->("test");
```

both examples above just spit out the whole function as if it were the name of a sub it could not find.  It looks like this:

```
Undefined subroutine [function then printed here]
```

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say that the scalar `$sub` contained the string `"foobar"`. If you then say `$sub->()`, then you are attempting to call a subroutine *named* `foobar`. If that subroutine does not exist, you will get an error.

You are trying to call a subroutine with the name `sub{ my $in = shift; if($in =~ /bla.*wam/){return 1;}}`, which is a thoroughly ridiculous name for a sub and obviously doesn't exist in your program. (And actually, since it's double-quoted, `$in` is probably interpolated as something without you realizing it.)

So, first of all, don't do that.

If you want an anonymous subroutine, make it like this:

```
my $sub = sub { my $in = shift; if($in =~ /bla.*wam/) { return 1; } };
```

Then execute it like this: `$sub->("test");`

If you *really* need to execute code in a string, then you can use `eval`.

```
my $sub = eval 'sub{ my $in = shift; if($in =~ /bla.*wam/) { return 1; } }';
```

That will evaluate the code in the string and return the result, which is a sub reference. Be very careful where these strings are coming from. Whoever makes them can make your program do whatever they want.

Comment: That was it, the eval - I had tried that but I had an error in the code I made so it was just evaluating as an error rather than code.  Thanks!  Yeah, not something to put on a website.

Answer (score 2):

Code and strings are not the same. Especially as you kind of misunderstand what your `$sub` actually is. Your codestring is a double-quoted string. Assuming `$in`  has the contents `bla wam`, then you assigned this to `$sub`:

```
"sub{ my bla wam = shift; if(bla wam =~ /bla.*wam/){return 1;}}";
```

This is such a syntax error.

However, you can assign anonymous subroutines directly to a variable:

```
my $sub = sub{
  my $in = shift;
  if ($in =~ /bla.*wam/) {
    return 1;
  }
};
```

and call it as in your examples (although I prefer the `$sub->(...)` style).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around the `sub`

```
$sub = sub { my $in = shift; if($in =~ /bla.*wam/){ return 1 } };
```